# Identifying which form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several forms in one page and all 3 of them call the same function for validation

```
validateForm()
```

the code for validation is

```
if (document.forms["myForm"]) {
        var fieldsToCheck = [ ['fname', lang.FirstName], ['lname', lang.LastName], ['email', lang.Email], ['phone_num', lang.PhoneNumber] ];
} // end if there is a form named myforms
else if (document.forms['addressform']) { // save a location form , ['town', lang.Town] is a dropdown
    var fieldsToCheck = [ ['nickname', lang.AddressNickname], ['street_no', lang.StreetNumber], ['address', lang.Address] ];

} // end forms
else if (document.forms['passform']) { // save a new password
    var fieldsToCheck = [ ['txtNewPassword', lang.NewPassword], ['ctxtNewPassword', lang.ConfirmPassword]];

} // end forms
```

and the forms are like this:

```
<form action="/action" name="passform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
```

where name is passform other forms have myform and addressform.

Now whenever I submit a form it always tries to find out the text inputs from the first form, which I guess is because `document.form["formname"]` checks to see if the form exists and proceeds, since it exists it does not matter which form you submitted, is there a way around this???

**important:** i know this is probably the wrong way to validate forms, since I could do form.submit() function validate etc, but unfortunately the code is not mine, so if there is a solution with this setup i prefer it!

Comment: Try this onsubmit="return validateForm(this)"

Comment: Ill amend my question because the way the forms are validated might not work with your suggestion

Comment: You could pass something as parameter for the function validateForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass this

```
onsubmit="return validateForm(this)"

function validateForm(elem) {
alert( elem.name);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YPn52/2/)

Comment: and how will this `var fieldsToCheck = [ ['fname', lang.FirstName], ['lname', lang.LastName], ['email', lang.Email], ['phone_num', lang.PhoneNumber] ];` validation thingy work with your example

Comment: if(elem.name=="myForm") based on the condition  you have to your requirement

Comment: well this is not ideal to my case since i was hoping not to change the onsubmit() call but it works

Answer (score 0):

use following to get id of form

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formId = this.id;  // "this" is a reference to the submitted form
});
```